# What API does Task Manager use to Dump a process

Tags: winapi, dump, taskmanager

Could anyone tell me what API does the windows inbuilt Task Manager use to dump the process I choose?

If I'm right, it's not the MiniDumpWriteDump. If not this, then what?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, it uses `MiniDumpWriteDump`.

Details (some unnecessary details was skipped):

In Windows 7 version, there is some wrapper function in the task manager executable gets called along with the process ID and the executable name, e.g `foo.exe`, whenever you want to dump a process.

It obtains a handle to the process using `OpenProcess` and stores it in some structure allocated in the heap using `HeapAlloc`.

It gets the temp directory in some local variable using `GetTempPathW`, append the executable name, e.g `foo.exe`, using `PathAppendW`, and removes the extension using `PathRemoveExtension` to becomes `foo` without `.exe` and then adds a new extension using `PathAddExtensionW`, and calls `PathYetAnotherMakeUniqueName` to check if the path not used or generate a new path like `foo(2).DMP`. Finally it gets a handle to the file using `CreateFile`.

It duplicate the handle using `DuplicateHandle` and store it in that structure and creates a new thread and pass the structure as an argument to the thread function.

The thread calls using the argument `MiniDumpWriteDump` with `DumpType` set to `0x1826`:

```
MiniDumpWithFullMemory | MiniDumpWithHandleData | MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules | MiniDumpWithFullMemoryInfo | MiniDumpWithThreadInfo
```

Answer (score 4):

There's only one way, MiniDumpWriteDump() is the way.

You can easily see this for yourself, run `dumpbin.exe /imports c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe` to see the functions it uses.  You'll see it imports MiniDumpWriteDump from DbgHelp.dll.  Also the reason that DbgHelp.dll gets shipped with Windows these days.